# Does/can the Graphics MeasureString method take the width of the container and line wrapping into account?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, system.drawing, measurestring

I have a need to calculate the height of a string given that I already know the width.

For example if have a string like "Curabitur semper ipsum semper nulla dictum, vel vulputate elit fringilla. Donec nec placerat purus, ut blandit lectus. Maecenas non molestie nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu."

I can use the following code to calculate the single-line width/height of that string.

```
using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)))
{
    System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font(
        FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Regular);
    SizeF bounds = gfx.MeasureString(
        message, f, new PointF(0, 0), 
        new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces));
}
```

However, what I would like to do is calculate the height of that string if it were within a div of 200px, accounting for line wraps.

At first I thought it was a function of the width of the image used to derive the Graphics object.

```
using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(500, 200)))
```

That didn't help and got the same single-line dimensions.

Does anyone know of any other tricks to get this?

Comment: Your problem definition is wrong.  You are not looking for the height of a string rather of a control and its content.  Knowing this, it should be obvious why `MeasureString` does not do the job.  In fact, the more I consider this problem the more confused I am by the concept itself.  What about padding?  Why are you doing this to begin with?  This problem has a lot of holes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to account for the WordBreak flag:

```
int h = 0;
using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics()) {
  using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Regular)) {
    h = TextRenderer.MeasureText(msg, f, new Size(200, 0), 
                                 TextFormatFlags.WordBreak).Height;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> given that I already know the width

Then you'll of course have to tell MeasureString() about that width, note that you never did that in your code.  MeasureString() has [several overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you need to use one that takes a SizeF.  Pass, say, `new SizeF(500, int.MaxValue)`.  The SizeF you'll get back will still have a Width of 500 but tells you the Height you are looking for.

Btw, only use DrawString/MeasureString when you draw to a printer.  For text that's rendered to the screen you should favor TextRenderer instead.